# redefining a macro not working as expected

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I am in C++ defining blocks that go in a special area of memory. I want to define a block, then define the address of the next block in a variable that gets redefined for each block.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define BASE_ADDRESS 0X1000

// type a gets 100 bytes
#define TYPE_A BASE_ADDRESS
#define NEXT_FREE_BLOCK (BASE_ADDRESS + 100)
    
// type b gets 200 bytes, starting at the next free address
#define TYPE_B NEXT_FREE_BLOCK
#undef NEXT_FREE_BLOCK
#define NEXT_FREE_BLOCK (TYPE_B + 200)

// ---end of RWW memory map---

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello free block " << NEXT_FREE_BLOCK << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Example code that I've looked up looks like this. But when I try to compile this, I get "compilation failed due to the following errors":

```
main.cpp:12:16: error: ‘NEXT_FREE_BLOCK’ was not declared in this scope
 #define TYPE_B NEXT_FREE_BLOCK
                ^
main.cpp:14:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘TYPE_B’
 #define NEXT_FREE_BLOCK (TYPE_B + 200)
                          ^~~~~~
main.cpp:20:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘NEXT_FREE_BLOCK’
     cout<<"Hello free block " << NEXT_FREE_BLOCK << endl;

                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I comment out the 'type b' lines, it runs as expected. If I comment out the #undef line, it tells me I've redefined the macro. I would like to redefine the macro without getting an error or warning; is there a way to do that?

Comment: macros do not allow recursion, if they would you would have infinite recursion.

Comment: Have you thought about using a custom linker script? Those usually let you define names for memory sections and where to put them. Of the top of my head it sounds a bit like the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: An `enum` would probably be a much simpler solution for this.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you intend to use `NEXT_FREE_BLOCK`?. There's probably a much more elegant solution out there but it's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Imagine more cases like type b as shown in the question -- I'm defining a number of blocks that all go into this special memory area. The things most likely to change are the size of the struct each one uses and the number of elements of that struct stored. It also stores these starting on page boundaries. So I want the compiler or preprocessor to calculate the address of the next block based on a size I give it, rather than having to recalculate it by hand each time. That's what's represented here by "base_address + 100" and "type_b + 200".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at this example:

```
#define MYMACRO 0 //MYMACRO = 0
#define ANOTHERMACRO MYMACRO //ANOTHERMACRO = MYMACRO = 0

int main() {
    return ANOTHERMACRO;
}
```

All good right?

But if we do this:

```
#define MYRECURSIVEMACRO 0 //MYRECURSIVEMACRO = 0

#define MYMACRO MYRECURSIVEMACRO //MYMACRO = MYRECURSIVEMACRO

#undef MYRECURSIVEMACRO // MYRECURSIVEMACRO does not exist
#define MYRECURSIVEMACRO (MYMACRO+10) //What was MYMACRO again? It was MYRECURSIVEMACRO, but now we are setting MYRECURSIVEMACRO, which right now is being defined, to itself plus 10, and now I am 100% confused

#define ANOTHERMACRO MYRECURSIVEMACRO //Now what?

int main() {
    return ANOTHERMACRO;
}
```

We get this:

```
1>C:\dev\Stack Overflow\Source.cpp(520,9): error C2065: 'MYMACRO': undeclared identifier
```

(At least for MSVC++)

Now if we look at this:

```
#define BASE_ADDRESS 0X1000 //BASE_ADDRESS = 0x1000

// type a gets 100 bytes
#define TYPE_A BASE_ADDRESS //TYPE_A = BASE_ADDRESS = 0x1000
#define NEXT_FREE_BLOCK (BASE_ADDRESS + 100) //NEXT_FREE_BLOCK = 0x1000 + 100
    
// type b gets 200 bytes, starting at the next free address
#define TYPE_B NEXT_FREE_BLOCK //TYPE_B = NEXT_FREE_BLOCK
#undef NEXT_FREE_BLOCK //NEXT_FREE_BLOCK is gone
#define NEXT_FREE_BLOCK (TYPE_B + 200) //Now what? Same problem as before!

// ---end of RWW memory map---
```

This is why it isn't working.

Comment: I did finally figure this out; it's the actual answer to my question. And just saying "an enum" is not a solution.